# Run user code in Jboss as a nonroot account

Tags: java, linux, jboss

Is there a way to designate an account in Jboss 7.1.1 to run user code under, without running the whole Jboss process as that account?

Comment: No. **But**, you might run two Jboss instances. Also, I would not run JBoss as root. Run JBoss as an user process and run a reverse proxy on port 80.

Comment: Oh well... I guess reverse proxy it is.